# Solve a Quadratic Equation in two variables using Python

Tags: linear-algebra, equation-solving, quadratic

I have got two equations, one linear say,

[image: formula]  , where *m* and *c* are constants 
and the other quadratic say,

[image: another]  , where *x1*, *y1* and *r* are constants.

Is there a way I can solve for x and y using Python ?

I could solve them on pen and paper finding the relation between x and y from the linear equation and substituting it in the other. There would be two roots satisfying the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Here is an example of how to solve a simple difference of squares equation, taken from their [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

```
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import Symbol

>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(x**2 - 1, x)

[-1, 1]
```

Regarding your specific problem, the solution will look something like this:

```
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> y = Symbol('y')

>>> solve( (x-c1)**2 + (y-c2)**2 - c3**2, x, y)
```

c1, c2 and c3 are the constants declared as variables earlier in your code.

Comment: Yes,it does work. For particular case, I get [152 - 15*sqrt(2)/2, 15*sqrt(2)/2 + 152] as the solution. Is there a way, I can get numeric value for it? How can I solve the expression sqrt(x) ?

Comment: You can evaluate one root, for example `152 - 15*sqrt(2)/2`, directly. You just need to make sure `sqrt` is imported by using `from math import sqrt`.

Comment: ```>>> from math import sqrt
>>> 152 - 15*sqrt(2)/2
>>> 141.3933982822018```

Answer (score 0):

Provided we know the constants: m, c, x1, y1, r  ; the code should look like this:

```
import sympy as sym
x,y = sym.symbols('x,y')
Eq1 = sym.Eq(y-mx,c)
Eq2 = sym.Eq((x-x1)**2 + (y-y1)**2, r**2)
sol = sym.solve([Eq1,Eq2],(x,y))
```